# (cordova) (inappbrowser) website redirection to virus pages

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, redirect, inappbrowser

I'm developing a cordova (android) application that uses inappbrowser to load a web site (this application is going to be the site application in the play store) , the problem is that when I test the application with any site it works perfectly , but when I test it with my needed site it redirect me to pages like that ,please help me:

[image]

Comment: Well that's probably because your "needed site" has ads like that.

Comment: check with some other links, try to open some other links from your app. if it will open with out above ads page then site have ads page which try to open.

Comment: Please give me your needed website URL .

Comment: @Naitik I already tried with some other links and it works perfectly , I encounter this problem only with my site :/

Comment: change to some other network and try... Not sure.. but that can be case..

Comment: @yuriy636 is there any solution ???

Comment: Please show me your code because i had tried this url its working quite fine for me. If you want the build of working app . I also can send you .

Comment: @HassanALi `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);   var ref;   function onDeviceReady() {   ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.afrikatv.net', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes, zoom=no');}`                                                                                                          **please send me your working app**

Comment: Give your email address. I will mail you the build .

Comment: @HassanALi tahag.imena@gmail.com

Comment: Check your email . If it is working for you I will post its whole code down here .

Comment: @HassanALi it'is working , please post the code here

Answer (score 2):

Here is my javascript file .

```
var ref= null;
var app = {

    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {


     var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://cordova.apache.com', '_blank', 'location=no');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstart);
         ref.addEventListener('loaderror', loaderror);
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop',loadstop);

    }



};
var loadstart=function (event) {

        $("#status-message").hide();
    }
var loadstop=function(event){

    $("frame").css("width","100%");
    $("frame").css("height","100%");
    $("frame").css("border","0");
}
var loaderror=function (params){

    $("#status-message").html("Sorry Server isn't responding yet.");
    $("#status-message").show();
}
app.initialize();
```

here is my html File .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="status-message" style="
    font-size: 208%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 36%;
    top: 55%;
">Please wait loading .............</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Please create a new cordova project and copy paste this code in it . And don't forget to add in appbrowser plugin your project that's all your are done

Comment: I still always the same problem

Comment: had you added inappbrowser plugin ? and do you have any error in console

Comment: I don't have problems , i installed properly the plugin ,logically plugin problems won't redirect me to virus pages, I have the same code as you , the site loads a the begining then it goes to virus sites , I think the site has adds ,

Comment: I don't have problems , i installed properly the plugin ,logically plugin problems won't redirect me to virus pages, I have the same code as you , the site loads a the begining then it goes to virus sites , I think the site has adds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118830/discussion-between-hassan-ali-and-imen-a).